# Just Int to Int

Tags: haskell, find

This code either returns the first factor of an Integer starting from 2 or returns nothing if it's a prime.

Example:  firstFactorOf 24 returns "Just 2"

Example: firstFactorOf 11 returns "Nothing"

My question is, how would I return the value 2 rather than "Just 2" if there is a factor or return the value x if there is no factor.

```
firstFactorOf x
    | m == Nothing = m
    | otherwise = m
    where m =(find p [2..x-1])
          p y = mod x y == 0

//RETURNS:
ghci> firstFactorOf 24
Just 2
ghci> firstFactorOf 11
Nothing
```

Comment: What should be returned in the case of `Nothing`?

Comment: Your question can be interpreted as either "How do I embed the assumption that `x` has a first factor (so I can avoid `Maybe` altogether)" or "Why doesn't Haskell have the notion of untagged unions". Which is it?

Comment: x should be returned.

Comment: I don't follow Alec.  I want it to either return the first factor of x or x.

Comment: @NickZiebert I am so sorry - I completely misunderstood your question for a completely different common problem people have! Just make a second function `firstFactorOf' x = maybe x (firstFactorOf x)`

Comment: @Alec I think you mean `fromMaybe`. `maybe` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: @liminalisht Yes. Or `maybe x id (firstFactorOf x)`. I'm all over the place. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

firstFactorOf x
    | m == Nothing = x
    | otherwise = fromJust m
    where m =(find p [2..x-1])
          p y = mod x y == 0
```

This was what I was after.  Not sure why you guys made this so complicated.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell is statically typed, meaning that you can define a function `Maybe a -> a`, but the question is what to do with the `Nothing` case.

Haskell has two functions that can be helpful here: [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) and [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust):

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
```

`fromJust` simply assumes that you will always provide it a `Just x`, and return `x`, in the other case, it will throw an exception.

`fromMaybe` on the other hand expects two parameters, the first - an `a` is the "default case" the value that should be returned in case of `Nothing`. Next it is given a `Maybe a` and in case it is a `Just x`, `x` is returned. In the other case (`Nothing`) as said before the default is returned.

In your comment you say `x` should be returned in case no such factor exists. So I propose you define a new function:

```
firstFactorOfJust :: Integral a => a -> a
firstFactorOfJust x = fromMaybe x $ firstFactorOf x
```

So this function `firstFactorOfJust` calls your `firstFactorOf` function and if the result is `Nothing`, `x` will be returned. In the other case, the outcome of `firstFactorOf` will be returned (but only the `Integral` part, not the `Just ...` part).

**EDIT (simplified)**

Based on your own answer that had the intend to simplify things a bit, I had the idea that you can simplify it a bit more:

```
firstFactorOf x | Just z <- find ((0 ==) . mod x) [2..x-1] = z
                | otherwise = x
```

and since we are all fan of optimization, you can already stop after `sqrt(x)` iterations (a well known optimization in prime checking):

```
isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

firstFactorOf x | Just z <- find ((0 ==) . mod x) [2..isqrt x] = z
                | otherwise = x
```

**Simplified question**

For some reason there was some peculiarly complicated aspect in your question:

```
firstFactorOf x
    | m == Nothing = m
    | otherwise = m
    where m =(find p [2..x-1])
          p y = mod x y == 0
```

Why do you use guards to make a distinction between two cases that generate the exact same output? You can fold this into:

```
firstFactorOf x = m
    where m = (find p [2..x-1])
          p y = mod x y == 0
```

and even further:

```
firstFactorOf x = find p [2..x-1]
               where p y = mod x y == 0
```

Comment: This was way overly complicated.  I posted my own solution that answers the question the way it was asked.  Why propose a new function for such an easy task??

Comment: You do not need to propose a new function. You could for instance not return `Nothing` to start with, but simply `x`. Your question was titled "`Just Int` to `Int`"... Looks to me that you then look for a "conversion". That's what people do when the *convert* a thing from *one type* to *another*. Furthermore it is considered *elegant* to return `Nothing` in case for instance a search fails.

Comment: Finally it thus looks that you simply copied the function from a textbook not knowing how it works (otherwise you would probably not let it return `Nothing` to begin with)...

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote it myself.  And thanks for making this personal and down voting all my stuff.

Comment: @NickZiebert: well it was some time ago I did downvote (usually I try to avoid arrogant people that use slang ;). Furthermore then I do not get why you introduced `Nothing` in the first place. What came into your mind to do that? I'm quite curious...

Comment: @NickZiebert: and since you're quite a fan of simplification, I've constructed a *two-liner* that even totally omits the `fromJust`...

Comment: Nice.  However, I needed 2 if statements so I can create an edge condition or a recursive call.  This was first step in creating a function that prints all factors of a #

Comment: Would you like to see the finished function to understand why I was asking this question in such a specific way?  I see why you were confused.

Comment: @NickZiebert: as far as I know a simple `filter` would be sufficient to generate all (prime)-factors. But yeah,problem. The thing that makes me a bit annoyed is that you ask for help. Both answers provide you with some functions to solve your problem. You use these functions in your own answer, but apparently have a problem with the fact that we introduced new functions, which is like a minor aspect. It is like criticizing a paper on special relativity because you do not like the square root being factored out.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Unfortunately, the above wasn't the answer I was looking for.  Your comment about only having to check up to the square root of the range of x definitely did help when creating my  allPrimeFactorsOf function.  The suggestion made it much quicker.  Thanks. (:

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to return the first factor of `x`, or `x`, then this should work:

```
firstFactorOf x =
  let
    p y = mod x y == 0
    m = (find p [2..x-1])
  in
  fromMaybe x m
```